# How to get the records grouping dates for a span of 3 days in SQL?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

It's getting difficult to group and display records every 5 days.

Here is my data:

```
FLIGHT_DATE LANDINGS    PILOTID COPILOTNAME MONT    DPT

11/16/2013  1   A   B   11  5.5
11/17/2013  1   A   B   11  13
11/19/2013  1   A   B   11  12.55
11/19/2013  1   A   B   11  4
11/21/2013  1   A   B   12  6
11/24/2013  1   A   B   12  6.03
11/25/2013  1   A   B   11  5.5
11/26/2013  1   A   B   11  13
11/26/2013  1   A   B   11  12.55
11/30/2013  1   A   B   11  4
12/1/2013   1   A   B   12  6
12/2/2013   1   A   B   12  6.03
```

I want to show it as below:

```
Week Start  Week End    DPT         
11/17/2013  11/21/2013  35.55           
11/22/2013  11/26/2013  37.08           
11/27/2013  12/1/2013   6           
12/2/2013   12/6/2013   6.03
```

Comment: On which basics you chose `11/17/2013` as Week Start?

Answer (score 4):

Here it is my proposed solution:

```
DECLARE @MinDate AS DATETIME = (SELECT MIN(flight_date) FROM flights);

WITH cte
AS
(
    SELECT
        flight_date, DATEDIFF(DAY, @MinDate, flight_date) AS NoDays,
        DATEDIFF(DAY, @MinDate, flight_date)/5 AS NoGroup,
        DPT
    FROM flights
)
SELECT  
    DATEADD(DAY, NoGroup*5, @MinDate) AS [Week Start],
    DATEADD(DAY, NoGroup*5+4, @MinDate) AS [Weed End],  
    SUM(DPT)
FROM cte
GROUP BY NoGroup;
```

The idea is to form groups of 5 days, then associate a record to a specific group based on division with 5. NoDays represents the days spent from MinDate to Flight_Date.

Comment: Yupp the above solution is more relevent to use. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query. You need to specify the start date from which you want to count and the number of days in each period (which seems to be 5 in your case) but please adjust those numbers as needed.

```
declare @startdate date = '20131117'
declare @interval int = 5

select dateadd(dd, @interval * (o.number - 1), @startdate) WeekStart, 
    dateadd(dd, @interval * o.number - 1, @startdate) WeekEnd,
    sum(d.DPT) DPT
from yourtable d
inner join
    (select ROW_NUMBER() over (order by object_id) as number from sys.all_objects) as o
on d.FLIGHT_DATE >= dateadd(dd, @interval * (o.number - 1), @startdate)
and d.FLIGHT_DATE < dateadd(dd, @interval * o.number, @startdate)
group by o.number
order by dateadd(dd, @interval * (o.number - 1), @startdate)
```

Comment: If i start my day span(7 days instead of 4 ) at 25/11 , record dated  on 01/12 is being added to next week

Comment: Just realise, your interval is 5, not 4.

Comment: Ok, Now I verified it's correct. But you have an error, for dates 11/27/2013  12/1/2013 it should be 10 as you have 2 records with 4 and 6 there.

Comment: Thanks ! Thank you very much script is working fine just looking on the comment you posted

Comment: yeah its adding up even for the same date and multiple record thank you very much for your support