# SQL Server: group dates by ranges

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, group-by

I have an SQL table with one column (dateRec) containing dates, format: yyyy-mm-dd.

Is there a way in SQL that I can define date ranges and then group all the items by these ranges ?
I would need the following groups here:

- group one = 0 - 7 days old
- group two = 8 - 14 days old
- group three = 15 - 30 days old
- group four = 31 - 60 days old
- group five = rest

**My standard query to fetch all items from that table:**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[FetchRequests]
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SELECT      subject,
                dateRec,
                category
    FROM        LogRequests
    WHERE       logStatus = 'active'
    ORDER BY    dateRec desc, subject
    FOR XML PATH('items'), ELEMENTS, TYPE, ROOT('ranks')

END
```

Thanks for any help with this, Tim.

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20323515/how-to-get-the-records-grouping-dates-for-a-span-of-3-days-in-sql/20323783#20323783.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need to do something like this

```
select t.range as [score range], count(*) as [number of occurences]
from (
  select case 
    when score between  0 and  9 then ' 0-9 '
    when score between 10 and 19 then '10-19'
    when score between 20 and 29 then '20-29'
    ...
    else '90-99' end as range
  from scores) t
group by t.range
```

Check this link [In SQL, how can you "group by" in ranges?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/232387/in-sql-how-can-you-group-by-in-ranges)

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you can do that by adding a new column which contains all the bands you require and then group by that column:

```
 SELECT      subject,
            dateRec,
            category
            ,case when datediff(day,dateRec,Getdate())<='7' then '0 - 7 days old'
                  when datediff(day,dateRec,Getdate()) between  '8' and '14' then '8 - 14 days old'
                   when datediff(day,dateRec,Getdate()) >60 then 'rest'
                   end Classes
       into #temp1
   FROM        LogRequests
   WHERE       logStatus = 'active'
   ORDER BY    dateRec desc, subject
```

I have missed couple of your ranges, but hopefully you got the logic

then Group by this column:

```
  select classes,
       Count(*)
      from #temp1

     begin drop table #temp1 end
```

Answer (score 6):

```
WITH ranges AS (
    SELECT
        range_id,
        ISNULL(DATEADD(day,range_start,CAST(GETDATE() AS date)),'0000-01-01') range_start,
        ISNULL(DATEADD(day,range_end  ,CAST(GETDATE() AS date)),'9999-12-31') range_end
    FROM (VALUES
        (1,  -7,  0),
        (2, -14, -8),
        (3, -30,-15),
        (4, -60,-31),
        (5,NULL,-61)
    ) r(range_id,range_start,range_end)
)
SELECT      subject,
            range_id,
            category
            COUNT(*) AS c,
FROM        LogRequests
WHERE       logStatus = 'active'
INNER JOIN  ranges ON dateRec BETWEEN range_start AND range_end
GROUP BY    subject,category,range_id
ORDER BY    range_id desc, subject
```