# SELECT with except several rows after current row by condition related with data in current row

Tags: mysql, sql

Help me with query. I need somehow group row but i dont know.
We have table with data of clients calls and this query need for statistic.

Condition: several calls from one person in some date range in one item.

table:

```
id  id_person  created_date  
1   1          2019-01-01 10:10:10  
2   1          2019-01-02 10:10:10  
3   1          2019-01-02 10:15:10  
4   1          2019-01-05 10:20:10  
5   2          2019-01-01 10:10:10  
6   2          2019-01-02 10:10:10  
7   3          2019-01-02 10:15:10
```

For e.g. we set gap param in 3 days

result of query:

```
1   1          2019-01-01 10:10:10  
4   1          2019-01-05 10:20:10  
5   2          2019-01-01 10:10:10  
7   3          2019-01-02 10:15:10
```

For e.g. we set gap param in 1 day

result of query:

```
1   1          2019-01-01 10:10:10  
3   1          2019-01-02 10:15:10  
4   1          2019-01-05 10:20:10  
5   2          2019-01-01 10:10:10  
7   3          2019-01-02 10:15:10
```

Need group by person_id and excepting rows that include in row.created_date+gap

Comment: what is your mysql version?

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve this yourself?

Comment: If you had calls on 1/1, 1/2, 1/3, and 1/4 and a gap of one day, what results would you expect?

Answer (score 0):

Your question has been asked before:

This solution should solve your issue and you can apply whichever gap parameter you want: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20323515/how-to-get-the-records-grouping-dates-for-a-span-of-3-days-in-sql/20323783#20323783)

```
SELECT  
    id_person,
    created_date,
    DATEADD(DAY, NoGroup*3, '1999-01-01') AS [Gap Start],
    DATEADD(DAY, NoGroup*3+2, '1999-01-01') AS [Gap End],  
    SUM(DPT)
FROM 
     (
    SELECT
        id_person,
        created_date, 
        DATEDIFF(DAY, '1999-01-01', created_date) AS NoDays,
        DATEDIFF(DAY, '1999-01-01', created_date)/3 AS NoGroup,
        DPT
    FROM your_table
     ) subquery
GROUP BY 
    id_person,
    created_date;
```

Comment: ha ha ha - execute your query and see how it could be a good shot - Good Luck

Comment: Ah - I was searching for SQL Server questions to answer...  MySQL has equivalent functions though...

Comment: @Serj See new link

Comment: @ColinMac Thank. If i use sql from link in my case i need renew MinDate for each person. I hope find solution without mysql procedure. I think best way realize this feature in app code. Because support procedure on sql server more difficult than in application

Comment: You could also NOT use the variable at all, and just hard code it to some date, like '1999-01-01', and it will work the same.

Comment: Also, you don't need to use a "CTE".  A CTE is just helpful syntax, you can rewrite it as a subqery.  I will post this.